# Yahoo API Internal Error while trying to create an app eid 3857713

Tags: yahoo-oauth

Trying to add an app and I received this error 
An internal error occurred (eid 3857713).

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Today the error is 
An internal error occurred (eid 5531225).

Answer (score 0):

This started working today. I'm guessing it was a yahoo glitch.